# form values will not save into PhpMyAdmin or MYSQL workbench is something wrong with my connection to the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

this is the code i am using to send data to phpmyadmin from my squidgameeditor3.php and insert2.php pages.
[squidgameeditor3.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw001.jpg)

```
<form action="insert2.php" method="POST" target="votar">
```

[insert3.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erd3I.jpg)

```
<?php



//Database Credentials
$host = 'localhost:3306';
$database = 'circulartexter';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

try {
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password); }
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "did catch that! ";
    echo $e->getMessage(); }

echo " #it works";



$sz1 = $_POST['sz1'];
$tp1 = $_POST['tp1'];
$lh1 = $_POST['lh1'];
$ft1 = $_POST['ft1'];
$sp1 = $_POST['sp1'];
$sh1 = $_POST['sh1'];
$sk1 = $_POST['sk1'];
$ma1 = $_POST['ma1'];





$sql = "INSERT INTO atrmain (`sz1`,`tp1`,`lh1`,`ft1`,`sp1`,`sh1`,`sk1`,`ma1`) SELECT ('$sz1','$tp1','$lh1','$ft1','$sp1','$sh1','$sk1','$ma1')";
```

?>

[phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSbNi.jpg)

i looked everywhere cant find the answer but i know its simple because i had this code working on another laptop before but it wont work on my new laptop so as soon as i get this question answered i will delete it

Comment: You never execute the query

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not a database. It's just a web-based tool for querying and managing MySQL databases.

Comment: You never execute the SQL, you just assign it to a string.

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection. You should learn to use prepared statements with parameters.

Comment: @Barmar im just testing thing out right now im working on more of a childrens app also so it like nothing to hack lol

Comment: You should learn proper coding from the start. There's no reason to be sloppy just because it's a test application.

Comment: @WADEYOMI it's not only because of potential security breach, but it avoid issues as well, like, in example, if your string contains quotes. It may even help your RDBMS to optimize the query by caching it and just wait for parameters